# How to get object with max value of 'number' for each distinct 'type' from array of objects?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have an array of objects:

```
const myArr = [
    { type: 'one', number: 1, fiedld: 'aaa' },
    { type: 'one', number: 2, field: 'bb' },
    { type: 'two', number: 2, field: 'xxx' }, 
    { type: 'two', number: 1, field: 'zz' }, 
    { type: 'two', number: 3, field: 'y' }
]
```

And I want to get objects with max value of `number` for each `type`.
So expected result is:

```
const newArr= [
           { type: 'one', number: 2, field: 'bb' }, 
           { type: 'two', number: 3, field: 'y' }
]
```

My current solution is:

```
sortByFields (field1, field2) {
    return ((x, y) => {
        return (
            (x[field1] > y[field1]) - (y[field1] > x[field1])
            || (x[field2] > y[field2]) - (y[field2] > x[field2])
        );
    })
}

myArr.sort(this.sortByFields('type', 'number'));
let newArr = [];
for (let i = 0; i < myArr.length - 1; i++) {
    if (myArr[i].type !== myArr[i + 1].type) {
        newArr.push(myArr[i]);
    }
    if (i === myArr.length - 2) {
        newArr.push(myArr[i + 1]);
    }
}
```

I'm beginner in JS, but I know that it can be done in more proper way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `reduce()` to make one object with keys for each type and then use `Object.values` to get array of objects.

```js
const myArr = [{ type: 'one', number: 1, fiedld: 'aaa' },{ type: 'one', number: 2, field: 'bb' },{ type: 'two', number: 2, field: 'xxx' }, { type: 'two', number: 1, field: 'zz' }, { type: 'two', number: 3, field: 'y' }]

var result = Object.values(myArr.reduce(function(r, e) {
  if(!r[e.type]) r[e.type] = e;
  else if(e.number > r[e.type].number) r[e.type] = e;
  return r;
}, {}))

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works fine for me. But I have 2 questions, if you don't mind:
1. What the 2 parameter of reduce mean (that curly braces)?
2. Is this proper for ES6?

Comment: That second param after callback function is just empty object that you pass as initial value to reduce. There is not much ES6 here except Object.values which is maybe even ES7

Comment: So this empty object is `r` in the callback function. Have I correctly understood?

Comment: @Yura Yes, that is correct. That is accumulator and you pass empty object as its starting or initial value.

Answer (score 0):

Solution with chaining of LoDash methods (need [LoDash library](https://lodash.com/)):

```js
const myArr = [{ type: 'one', number: 1, field: 'aaa' },
               { type: 'one', number: 2, field: 'bb' },
               { type: 'two', number: 2, field: 'xxx' }, 
               { type: 'two', number: 1, field: 'zz' }, 
               { type: 'two', number: 3, field: 'y' }
    ];

const result = _(myArr)
  .groupBy('type')
  .map(_.unary(_.partialRight(_.maxBy, 'number')))
  .value()

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You copuld use a straight forward approach with a hash table.

```js
var array = [{ type: 'one', number: 1, fiedld: 'aaa' }, { type: 'one', number: 2, field: 'bb' }, { type: 'two', number: 2, field: 'xxx' }, { type: 'two', number: 1, field: 'zz' }, { type: 'two', number: 3, field: 'y' }],
    indices = Object.create(null),
    result = array.reduce(function (r, a) {
        if (!(a.type in indices)) {
            indices[a.type] = r.push(a) - 1;
            return r;
        }
        if (a.number > r[indices[a.type]].number) {
            r[indices[a.type]] = a;
        }
        return r;
    }, []);
    
console.log(result)
```